Putting the contents of a binary file into an unsigned char array using ifstream
I have a binary file (filename is in argv[1], size is always 64KiB) which I need to put the contents of into an unsigned char array using ifstream. I have tried to do so using the >> operator, but that only put garbage data into the array.
Here is the code:
  unsigned char ROMInit[65536];
  std::ifstream ROMFile(argv[1], std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
    ROMFile >> ROMInit[i];
  }

How can I put the contents of the file into the array?

Try ROMInit[i] = testFile.get(); but you might prefer to use the read method and forget about the loop.

Your error is using >> for binary data. >> is for textual data, so, for example, it skips whitespace.

testFile.read(...)?

@john Sorry, I copied the wrong code (nothing changes except testFile becomes ROMFile), but I will try what you said except with ROMFile.

This worked, can you post your comment as an answer?

@furybowser The best answer is to use the the read method ROMFile.read((char*)ROMInit, 65536); No need for a for loop, just read all the data in one go.

Well that works too, but either way, I need an actual answer in order to accept one.

@furybowser -- you can write your own answer and accept it.
